# Can not call my associate table in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can not call my associate table in my view. have tried this. it is an application that only adds to the players. after the press "start game" and then he should come to the result view where the results of all players. then I will of course have the name of the "players" table and then the binding results from the "results" table. now in quire, I enter bidningen in the background as long as

view:

```
<% @playersname.each do |p|%> 
 <ul>
    <li><%= p.name %></li>
    <li><%= p.results.try(:result) %></li>
 </ul>
<%end%>
```

Controller:

```
 class ResultsController < ApplicationController
 def index
        @playersname = Player.all
  end
```

end

Model:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :players
end
```

migration:

```
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :results do |t|
        t.string "result", :limit => 40
        t.string "cal", :limit => 40
            t.string "sum",:limit => 300
            t.timestamps
     end
  end
```

end

Comment: Does your problem get fixed if you add `belongs_to :result` in your player model?

Comment: No Paul, i have


class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :result
end

Answer (score 0):

The CreateResults migration miss the player_id column.

Do `belongs_to :player` in your Result class and correct the migration (or do another one).

[Edit] I wasn't clear enough : I think you inverted the relationship logic.
You actually did the "one result has several players".
I suppose you want that a player has several results ?

```
class Player
  has_many :results
end

class Result
  belongs_to :player
end
```

So you can do :

```
@myplayer = Player.all.first
@myplayer.results #it is an array of player's results
@myplayerresult = @myplayer.results.first
puts @myplayerresult.result
```

If you want a one-to-one relationship, consider replacing `has_many :results` by `has_one :result` and so you can do `@myplayer.result` to get your result.

Comment: Player is not my problem. there is result. i set result.try... but i found error "Could not find table 'results'"

Comment: As for now, I think you inverted the relationship logic. See my edit. And tell more about the relation you want between a Player and a Result.